# Is there a sci.stats.moment function for binned data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a function which calculates the n-th central moment
(same as the one out of scipy.stats.moment)
for my binned data (Out of the numpy.histogram function).

```
# Generate normal distributed data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.normal(size=500,loc=1,scale=2)
H = np.histogram(data,bins=50) 
plt.scatter(H[1][:-1],H[0])
plt.show()
```

for my above code example the results should be (0,4,0,48) for the first four moments as there sigma = 2 (for the central moment).

Comment: Shouldn't the second moment (variance) be 4 in this case? I am not aware of any functions in scipy.stats that work on histograms (this is usually less accurate than using the raw data). Any reason why you can't compute the moments directly from `data`?

Comment: Sorry, your right it should be 4. I will calculate it the next time directly but i it is a long time simulation and i wanted to use the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with binned data is essentially the same as working with weighted data. One uses the midpoint of each bin as a data point, and the count of that bin as its weight. If `scipy.stats.moment` supported weights, we could do this computation directly. As is, use the method [`numpy.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) which supports weights.

```
midpoints = 0.5 * (H[1][1:] + H[1][:-1])
ev = np.average(midpoints, weights = H[0])
print(ev)
for k in range(2, 5):
  print(np.average((midpoints - ev)**k, weights = H[0]))
```

Output (obviously random):

```
1.08242834443
4.21602099286
0.713129264647
51.6257736139
```

I didn't print the centered 1st moment (which is 0 by construction), printing the expected value instead. Theoretically*, these are 1, 4, 0, 48 but for any given sample, there is going to be some deviation from the parameters of the distribution.

(*) Not exactly. In the formula for variance I didn't include the correction factor `n/(n-1)` (where n is the total size of data set, i.e., the sum of weights). This factor adjusts the [sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) so it becomes an unbiased estimator of the population variance. You can include it if you like. Similar adjustments are probably needed for higher-order moments (if the goal is to have unbiased estimators), but I'd have to look this up, and in any case this is not a statistics site.